# Como passar variável fstream para outra função?

Tags: c++, arquivo

Estou tentando passar um arquivo binário que já está aberto, para uma função. Porém, recebo o seguinte erro:

> error: use of deleted function.

Código:

```
void abreBin(){
    fstream arq_bin("registro.bin", ios::in|ios::binary)
    ....
    // remove é uma funcao do tipo bool
    if(Remove(arq_bin)) // <--- erro acusa nesta linha
        cout << "item removido" << endl;
    else
        cout << "item nao encontrado" << endl;
}
```

Obs: O erro só acontece quando tento passar a variável `arq_bin` para a outra função.

Tentei usar includes de bibliotecas do tipo `bool`, mas não deu certo. Tentei passar outras variáveis pra função e vi que o problema só ocorre com variável `fstream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro provavelmente acontece porque `Remove()` foi definida para receber um parâmetro do tipo `fstream` por valor (cópia), mas `fstream` não permite a operação de cópia.

Altere `Remove()` para que ela receba um parâmetro por referência, como abaixo:

`bool Remove(fstream& arq)`

Comment: Justamente, eu descobri essa solução ontem, tava indo responder agora kkk. Só que não entendi o motivo do `fstream` não permitir operação de cópia, você sabe explicar?

Comment: A operação de cópia não faz sentido para streams. Você pode entender um stream como um objeto que "aponta" para uma entrada/saída de dados, e não os armazena. Ao copiar um stream você teria dois objetos "apontando" para uma mesma entrada/saída. Imagine que em um dos objetos você fechasse essa entrada/saída: você continuaria com um objeto apontando para ela, o que adiciona insegurança no código, se por exemplo tentasse ler esta entrada/saída que foi fechada.